# How to pass groovy variable to powershell in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to pass groovy variable to powershell script inside of jenkins pipeline, all in the same place but i don't know how. i tried different ways without success.

I require this to obtain the name of the person who approved the step of PIPELINE and pass it to powershell, which connects with SQL SERVER

```
    stage('Step1'){
      steps{ 
        script{
         def approverDEV
         approverDEV = input id: 'test', message: 'Hello', ok: 'Proceed?', parameters: [choice(choices: 'apple\npear\norange', description: 'Select a fruit for this build', name: 'FRUIT'), string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'myparam')], submitter: 'user1,user2,group1', submitterParameter: 'APPROVER'

          echo "This build was approved by: ${approverDEV['APPROVER']}"
        }
      }
    }

stage('Step2'){
  steps{ 
    script{
      powershell ('''
       # Example echo "${approverDEV['APPROVER']}"
       # BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK :(
      ''')
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the output is the name of the approver stored in the variable GROOVY approverDEV

Comment: The single-quoted string not evaluated. Use double-quoted: `"""  $a """`

Comment: but these is not the problem is the way

Comment: then it's not clear what's the problem...

Comment: @daggett sorry my bad, you have reason. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dagett is correct, use double-quotes around the powershell script, then the variables will be evaluated:

```
script{
  powershell ("""
   # Example echo "${approverDEV['APPROVER']}"
   # BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK :(
  """)
}
```

Using triple double quotes in Groovy is called 'multi-line GString'. In a GString, variables will be evaluated before creating the actual String.

Comment: Thanks!, you have reason.
@daggett. Thanks

Comment: i have another problem with the same. if i declare a variable powshell inside at execute the job i have the next problem:

No such property: Params for class: WorkflowScript

script{
  powershell ("""
   $Params = "Hello Word!" 
  """)
}

Comment: Not really sure but it sounds like the variable is not in scope. Is it a Groovy variable? Otherwise you may need to escaoe it if it is intended as a powershell variable.